# What is the correct method to be called in global.asax when application is closed in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

The events in `global.asax` are :

[image]

Ok then. I want to close connection to database when the application stops. I use MSSQL Server 2005.

I want to use:

```
  protected void Application_End( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
     // close database connection
  }
```

and

```
  protected void Application_EndRequest( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
     // close database connection
  }
```

What one of two above methods is good choice to close connection to database ?

Or it is good idea to manage connections in `global.asax` ?

Comment: If you have an open connection during the lifetime of the application, you are doing something wrong. How are you opening connections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it is good idea to manage connections in `global.asax`?

It is a terrible idea.

Connections are expensive resources that should only be used and open for as short a time as possible. Normally connection pooling is the mechanism used to ensure responsiveness from the database.

You should be closing the connections where they are opened, best practice is to use a `using` statement to ensure proper disposal:

```
using(var con = new Connection("my connection string"))
{
}
```

Comment: I used that `using` keyword. I thought to above idea. the terrible idea :)). Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is a good choice IMO.

> Or it is good idea to manage connections in global.asax ?

No.  Connections are managed by the [Connection Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)